# LibGDX doesn't clean buffer

Tags: java, android, libgdx, buffer

I don't know how I can clear the buffer in libGDX, in this case, 
                    GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT doesn't work.

```
package com.mygdx.game.Screens;

import Artifacts.Champ;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.SpriteDrawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Align;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;
import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    private Stage stage;
    private Game game;
    ArrayList <Champ> champs=new ArrayList();;

    public GameScreen(Game aGame) {
        game = aGame;
        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
        ImageButton pj;

        Table camp;
        champs.add(new Champ("Ximet",new Texture("Champ/Ximet.png")));        
        champs.add(new Champ("Jordi",new Texture("Champ/Jordi.jpg")));        
        champs.add(new Champ("Camilo",new Texture("Champ/Camilo.jpg")));        
        champs.add(new Champ("Vicent",new Texture("Champ/Vicent.jpg")));
        int x=100, y=250;
        for (final Champ champ : champs) {
            camp=new Table();
            pj=new ImageButton(new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(champ.getLogo())));
            pj.setPosition(x, y);
            camp.add(pj).size(100, 100);
            camp.setPosition(x, y);
            x=x+100;
            camp.addListener(new InputListener(){
                @Override
                public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                    Label name = new Label(champ.nom, MyGdxGame.gameSkin,"big-black");
                    name.setPosition(10,400);
                    stage.addActor(name);
                }
                @Override
                public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            stage.addActor(camp);
        }
        Label title = new Label("Select Champ", MyGdxGame.gameSkin,"big-black");
        title.setAlignment(Align.center);
        title.setY(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()*2/3);
        title.setWidth(Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
        stage.addActor(title);

        TextButton backButton = new TextButton("Back",MyGdxGame.gameSkin);
        backButton.setWidth(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2);
        backButton.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-backButton.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/4-backButton.getHeight()/2);
        backButton.addListener(new InputListener(){

            @Override
            public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                game.setScreen(new Principal((MyGdxGame)game));
            }
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        stage.addActor(backButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        Gdx.app.log("MainScreen","show");
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }

}
```

That screen shows you all the players and when you pick one of them, on the topside will appear her name, it works, but when I pick another different, the name still there.

P.S.1 I'm begginer, just learning LigGDX picking code, and I'm trying to do a rpg game.

P.S.2 For-loop prints on the screen the arraylist of champions, adding them to a button for select one of them, if you know another way more easy and optimized, I'll appreciate.

P.S.3 I know that initialize in the loop the table isn't recommended. If I initialize outside the loop, when I pick a champion, in the topside shows the name of all the objects in the arraylist.

Comment: Not sure I understand your original issue regarding screen clearing, but you say if you pick one player, the name shows up but picking subsequent players continues to show the first name. That is because your camp.addListener touchUp method adds the name to the stage -- stage.addActor(name); -- but I don't think you ever remove it from the stage. So every time you render afterward, you will still show this name as the actor is still on stage. You need to remove the name Label from the stage when you change players

Comment: It looks like you only ever add labels and you don't have any code to remove labels. You need to add some code to remove the labels when a new champ is selected or use 1 label and just change the text depending on the champ selected.